# How do i send a saved text file as an email attachment

Tags: iphone, email, xcode4, ios4

I have an app which is sending data collected via an email as an attachment. I use the following code to create and save the data to a file called 'leads.xml' in my docs folder.

```
NSArray *sysPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
NSString *sysFilePath = [sysPath objectAtIndex:0];
[picker addAttachmentData:sysFilePath mimeType:@"text/xml" fileName:@"leads.xml"];

.
.
.

[emailBody writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

I then try to send the saved file as an attachment using this code -

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/leads.xml", docDirectory];
```

When it runs I get an error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: which error you are getting..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mail want a `NSData` object, contain the files content not a path.
You will need to load the file into a `NSData` object like:

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"leads.xml"];

NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[picker addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/xml" fileName:@"leads.xml"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply the data, not a file path:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sysFilePath];
[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/xml" fileName:fileName];
```

Docs:

```
- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename
```

attachment:

The **data to attach**. Typically, this is the contents of a file that you want to include. This parameter must not be nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if(mailController)
            {
                mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
               // NSLog(@"current index:%d",currentIndex_);
                NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00%d",currentIndex_+43];
              //  NSLog(@"string:%@",string);
                NSString *imageIndex = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:string ofType:@"jpg"];

                NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageIndex];

                [mailController addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/jpg" fileName:@"Report"];
                [mailController setSubject:@"your subject"];
                [mailController setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
                [self presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
                [mailController release];
            }
```

I am sending image here instead of it you can send your text file.
This may help you

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things...

You can check the file system for the simulator at:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/...
```

and see if your file is actually being saved where you expect.

Second thing:
`NSString` actually has a load of convenience methods for working with file paths so you don't have to check for trailing slashes and other junk. You should always use them when working with file paths.

**Working with Paths**

```
+ pathWithComponents:
– pathComponents
– completePathIntoString:caseSensitive:matchesIntoArray:filterTypes:
– fileSystemRepresentation
– getFileSystemRepresentation:maxLength:
– isAbsolutePath
– lastPathComponent
– pathExtension
– stringByAbbreviatingWithTildeInPath
– stringByAppendingPathComponent:
– stringByAppendingPathExtension:
– stringByDeletingLastPathComponent
– stringByDeletingPathExtension
– stringByExpandingTildeInPath
– stringByResolvingSymlinksInPath
– stringByStandardizingPath
– stringsByAppendingPaths:
```

Comment: The problem is not as much in the building of the file path, but in the adding of the files data to the email.